# Trying to add a radio button and only select one button at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to add another radio button and get user to chose only one at a time.

I dont want to change _onChangeIsConfig.
What can i change in my code to make the button work without changing _onChangeIsConfig

```
_onChangeIsConfig(event){
      FirmwareUpgradeDialogActions.updateState('isConfig', event.target.checked);

    }

<FormControlLabel
    control={
       <Radio
       checked={this.state.isConfig === 'firmware-isconfig'}
       onChange={this._onChangeIsConfig}
       value="firmware-isconfig"
          />
         }
     label={this.context.intl.formatMessage({id: 'network.isconfig'})}
                                   />

    <FormControlLabel
         control={
            <Radio

          checked={this.state.isConfig === 'firmware-image-isconfig'}

           onChange={this._onChangeIsConfig}
           value="firmware-image-isconfig"
        />
    }
```

Comment: If you want at least 1 checked you could go with the logic that if `isConfig` is true then the first label is checked, otherwise, the second label is checked

Comment: As @Icepickle already mentioned, if don't like to do updates, you'll have to go as he suggested it. But if you can make use of name and value props, you'll get radio button toggle for free from HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you want a pretty binary state (you cannot really do much more, if you only keep the one boolean flag), then change your jsx like so

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={
       <Radio
           checked={!!this.state.isConfig}
           onChange={this._onChangeIsConfig}
           value="firmware-isconfig"
           />
    }
    label={this.context.intl.formatMessage({id: 'network.isconfig'})}
/>

<FormControlLabel
     control={
        <Radio
            checked={!this.state.isConfig}
            onChange={() => this._onChangeIsConfig( { target: { checked: false } } )}
            value="firmware-image-isconfig"
        />
     }
 />
```

This would give you either of the 2 radio controls always checked, how you handle it afterwards would then be up to you. You cannot have any more however if you don't want to change how your state updates

Comment: This works too but it is not letting me switch back between buttons. I don't want to change the state because it associated with all the other file, i am trying to avoid changing all the files

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the onchange event on the second one, so I just send now a fake event to your old method ;)